# Help with get_categories code

Tags: php, functions, categories, description

I have listed the following code below, and where it is pulling the sub-title into the banner I need to change this to pull the category of the linked article instead. This is the link to the website homepage: https://stblazeydistrictsnooker.co.uk/

Can anyone help me figure this out please?

```
<?php
                                $random_banner = get_posts(array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'use_as_banner',
                                            'value' => true,
                                        )
                                    )
                                ));
                                if(!sizeof($random_banner)) {
                                    $banner_link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
                                    $banner_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
                                    $banner_sub_title = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
                                } else {
                                    $banner_link = get_the_permalink($random_banner[0]);
                                    $banner_title = get_the_title($random_banner[0]);
                                    $banner_sub_title = get_the_excerpt($random_banner[0]);
                                    if($banner_sub_title == '') {
                                        $banner_sub_title = wp_trim_words( get_post_field('post_content', $random_banner[0]), 10, null );
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo $banner_link; ?>"><?php echo $banner_title; ?></a></h1>
                            <h2 class="site-description"><a href="<?php echo $banner_link; ?>"><?php echo $banner_sub_title; ?></a></h2>
                        </hgroup>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is the 'THE 2023-2024 SNOOKER SEASON FIXTURES, TEAMS, PLAYERS AND HANDICAPS ARE NOW AVAILABLE' a post? And are you wanting to link this to the category it's assigned to?

Comment: Yes it's a post, it's already linking to that post, but I need the category in that post to show up and link to the post